# how to Best Fit(All Columns) in a GridControl

Tags: c#, devexpress, gridcontrol

How to best fit all the columns in a grid control when form is loaded. I do have a button as shown in the following picture to do that when i right click the header of the grid control, but as opposed to this I want this event to be fired automatically when the form is loaded. I don't want to do this by right clicking the header of the grid control and than clicking the Best Fit(all columns) button to best fit all the columns.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it.

```
if (view is GridView)
{
   // auto best fit...
   (view as GridView).BestFitMaxRowCount = 5000;   // just to avoid to many compares
   (view as GridView).BestFitColumns();
   foreach (GridColumn item in (view as GridView).Columns) // reduce the width of very wide columns
   {
      item.Width = (item.Width > 1000) ? 1000 : item.Width;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

following Code BestFit All the Columns Provided that FixedWidth of All the Columns is set to False

```
GridView.BestFitColumns();
```

Comment: What version of DevExpress you were using? Do you know how to do it in 13 or 14?

Comment: it is probably version independent. it should work in every version. don't forget to set FixedWidth of all the columns to false